# Tkinter GUI - deiconify() top level window from a top level window class in another module

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

So i think this is possible but I'm not sure...
Im creating a login system for my program, the main screen is a tinter GUI root window, when this is created it is then .withdraw() and the top level login window is opened (this is stored in another module in a class). When the username and password are correct in the login top level window i want to .deiconify() the root window from within a method of the login window class. Is this possible and if so how....
Sorry i haven't got the code with me so can't upload any right now
Thank You!

Comment: Please try and include some code example of what you have already tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure it's possible.  Just call `root.deiconify()`.  You can either pass `root` as a parameter to the login window, or make it a global variable.

Comment: Thank You! That really helped me figure it out!